# "to comment out" before the era of programming

Tags: word-usage

I think many people here are programmers since stack sites started out as stackoverflow originally, which is about programming.

My question here is about the phrasal verb "to comment out". It makes a lot of sense to those who know that in programming you can easily turn some part of the code (usually a line) into simply a comment that would have no bearing on the code's execution. For example,

```
print: Hello world
```

can be easily turned into a comment in this way:

```
; print: Hello world
```

Programmers would say in this case, "I have commented out the line." It is absolutely logical and makes sense to me. However, I wonder if this phrasal verb ever was used before the programming came about. Did it exist in those times? If yes, in what situation it was normally used then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from a few minutes searching on Google Books, *comment out* has not been used as a phrasal verb other than in the programming sense.

Here's the most interesting use of the collocation:

> 1689   Abednego Seller, [*The History of Passive Obedience Since the Reformation*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hUJCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA97) 97   We have ſeen Rebellion commented out of Rom. xiii.

Since Romans 13 is all about obedience ("Let every soul be subject unto the higher powers ...") I think this must be *comment* used in the obsolete sense "devise, contrive, invent" [*OED*].

Comment: Umm ... I think you've got hold of the right sense of *comment*; but if you look at the passage Seller is [quoting](http://books.google.com/books?id=4YvPAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=He+that+makes+his+prince+despised+and+undervalued&source=bl&ots=ZHL5ybIYvK&sig=tbS6MakxDjU3xQPrZy_dWQJ9WXw&hl=en#v=onepage&q=Rebellion%20commented&f=false), it's clear that *commented out of* means *justified on the factitious basis of* Rom.xiii.

Answer (score 4):

I have never encountered this usage outside programming, and there's no reason to expect it would have existed before then.

"Commenting out" means instructing the compiler or interpreter to ignore the text in question. The primary purpose of incorporating the instruction was to allow the programmer to insert comments which would make his code more intelligible - what you might now, if you were as frivolous as I, distinguish as "commenting in". Programmers quickly realized, however, that the instruction also permitted them to de-activate code segments for test or debugging purposes, and it is that which is the origin of "commenting out".

No such practice is called for in ordinary literary texts. Comments of various sorts may be distinguished "in line" through puncutation or a change of script or type; or inserted in margins or at the foot of a page; or banished to the end of a text. Deletions are accomplished by, well, deletion, or overstriking, or excision.

Comment: The term is also sometimes used when talking about documentation and XML/HTML files (e.g. web pages).  These uses post-date and (I assume) derive from the programming usage, but it's not *just* a programming term any more.

Comment: You say *compiler* and *interpreter* as though those were somehow different things. :)  An *assembler* will also ignore comments. This suggests room for another word altogether.

Comment: @tchrist  Perhaps usage has changed since I was a programmer in the '80s. Then a *compiler* translated code into a freestanding  executable program, while an *interpreter* translated and executed code line by line; a *compiler* was thus just a more sophisticated *assembler*.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, it doesn’t really work that way anymore, apart from shell scripts and batch jobs and the like. Most so-called “interpreted” programming languages first compile into some form of intermediary code, like p-code or byte code, and turn that over to either an interpreter (execution runtime) directly, or pass it through a code-generation phase to produce machine language to pass to the firmware interpreter. Essentially, *all* code is both compiled and interpreted. Uncompiled p-code has no comments left, because the compiler doesn’t pass those to the interpreter. Interpreters get none.

Comment: @tchrist  thank you. Please feel free to edit my answer for forward-compatibility.

Comment: @tchrist Yes but it's still a useful and meaningful distinction in that compiled code (or pre-compiled code) won't generate compilation errors.  To me it sounds like the old anti-OO argument that "it all ends up in the same instruction set anyway".  Hmm, thinking about it I'm fuzzy on where you'd draw the line between shell scripts and interpreted languages.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a similar verb to commenting out for non-programming settings, but "Comment Out" derives directly from the fact that you are using the comment syntax to remove something. The semicolon in your example wasn't originally intended to remove data, it was intended to allow programmers to make comment in their code for future reference.

Without the reference point of the commenting code syntax, the term "Comment Out" would hold no meaning.